# Как правильно выполнить проверки

Tags: javascript, typescript

Есть такой интерфейс

```
export interface DataTransport {
    hand: Card[];
    table: Card[];
    status: boolean;
    score: number;
    round: number;
    finish: string;
    log: Log;
}
```

пытаюсь проверять так

```
private isDefined() {
    return this.data.hand !== undefined && this.data.table !== undefined;
}
```

Знаю что можно как то через instanceof или ещё как то но должно быть нормальное решение.

```
this.socket.on('info',(data: HeartsInterface.DataTransport) => {
    if(this.isDefined()){
        console.log('BINGO');
    }
});
```

Comment: что значит _нормальное_? чем не устраивает текущая реализация?

Comment: @Grundy хочу проверить все поля и чтобы ещё типы совпадали в идеале

Comment: типы совпадали с чем?

Comment: @Grundy с интерфейсом

Comment: у интерфейса с интерфейсом? Попробуй развернуть вопрос, сейчас непонятно что именно и когда ты хочешь проверить

Comment: То есть ты хочешь убедиться, что по сети пришли все поля? тогда только ручной проверкой этих полей

Comment: @Grundy, где-то видел модуль, который умеет по интерфейсу генерировать runtime-проверку.

Comment: @Qwertiy, модуль для чего?

Comment: @Grundy, написано начиная со слова "который" ;)

Comment: @Qwertiy, :-D я имел ввиду модуль typescript? npm? может для сборщика какого-нибудь? :-)

Comment: @Grundy, npm-модуль. Я не очень помню, т. к. не пользовался. Интерфейсы не существуют в рантайме, так что это что-то, генерирующее дополнительный код при компиляции typescript'а.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/52282/discussion-between-grundy-and-qwertiy).